# Application of Artificial Intelligence in Semantic Web

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, semantic-web

I need to write an essay or a research for the subject Artificial Intelligence. There are many possible topics I can choose from plus we are also allowed to write about any other topic of interest.

One of the topics is Semantic Web. I would like to write about use of AI algorithms in relation with Semantic Web.

Could you please suggest me some good topics from this area?

Is PageRank a good topic? Is it related enough to both Semantic Web and AI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write about how different types of reasoning systems handle certain challenges that are faced in Semantic Web.

Also, I think PageRank would be a very good topic. It does relate enough to both Semantic Web and AI. You should easily be able to dig up enough information about it. However, you may find yourself writing a paper about what has already happened instead of a paper that may include your own ideas.

Answer (score 4):

Analyzing social graphs and suggesting friends based on microformats embedded in disparate social networking sites could be interesting.

Answer (score 2):

OpenCalais is a web service that augments unstructured text with semantic metadata (and can therefore partially automate the creation of a semantic web): http://www.opencalais.com/about

You could write about the challenges of implementing named entity recognition and natural language processing for extracting facts and events.

This paper proposes using Wikipedia articles as a dictionary of named entities: http://www.aaai.org/Papers/IJCAI/2007/IJCAI07-259.pdf

This may also shed some light on the NLP challenge: http://www.cyc.com/cyc/technology/whatiscyc_dir/cycrandd/areasofrandd_dir/nlu

Answer (score 1):

Maybe to write about the more detailed analysis of web documents? In this case you would need to touch the NLP topic which belongs to AI.